# Convert String to Number with Format

Tags: java, string-formatting

I was wondering if there is an existing method to convert a formatted number String to number, such as "123,456.78" to 123456.78

Basically, unlike DecimalFormat function, which turns a double variable to a String following that a given format such as "###,###.##" pattern. I want to implement a reverse of this functionality, which turns a String with "###,###.##" format to a double. Is there APIs to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: you just want to convert string format right? why don't you convert string into integer or double using **parseInt or valueOf?**

Comment: Won't just removing the commas and then using `Double.parseDouble()` work?

Comment: You did check the [documentation for DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) and [its superclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html), right?  You did notice that it has not only `format` methods, but also `parse` methods like [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-), right?

Comment: DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).parse("4,265,858.26"). will this help?

Comment: @VGR that should be an answer, since it is correct.

Comment: @ShivaShinde if your String contains ',', parseDouble will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have looked through the [documentation for DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) and [its superclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).  You would have discovered that it has not only `format` methods, but also `parse` methods like [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-).

The easiest way to do what you want is:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
Number value = format.parse(string);

// If you specifically want a double...
double d = value.doubleValue();
```

You will have to catch ParseException and deal with it.  How you do that depends on what you want to do when your string does not represent a valid numeric value.  If it's user input, you may want to ask the user to enter the text again.

Comment: Thank you, this is the one I am thinking

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do this

```
    String number = "20,000,000";
    int x = Integer.parseInt(number.replace(",", ""));
    System.out.println(x);
```

You just replace the `char's` that not belong to a number with `""` and then parse it into a primitive.

```
    String number = "20,000,000.56";
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(5);
    double x = Double.parseDouble(number.replace(",", ""));
    System.out.println(df.format(x));
```

It is a bit different for a Double cause it will display the exponential output and you'll have to prevent that. The code above does that.

```
    df.format(x)
```

Returns a String but you can cast it with the `Double.parseDouble` method

---

Here's a method using a `Regex` and the `replace` method if you have more than one delimiter and you know them all :

Let's say the delimiters here are "-" and ","

```
double x = Double.parseDouble(number.replace("[-,]", "");
```

Comment: OP asked to parse to a double, not an int.

Comment: That's not without any API, that's using the `Integer.parseInt` and `String.replace` APIs. Also, OP already knows about `DecimalFormat`, which does exactly what is requested i.e., parse a number with commas to a double, which your answer does not do.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the only way. I need into consideration of locale to parse the string, since "," may not be the only delimiter. That is why I want to see if there exists APIs that taken a pattern format string.

Comment: @YassinHH Sure, but since you're creating a DecimalFormat anyway, I don't know why you wouldn't just use it to parse the string.